# Can I view Nvidia GPU usage?

Tags: gpu, nouveau, system-monitor

I know that I can view CPU usage using System Monitor:

[image: 8-core CPU usage in Ubuntu]

Is there such a tool for viewing GPU usage, as well?

Comment: this ques has already been answered 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage
hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is in the proprietary drivers, it is called `nvidia-smi`. 
See [1]

[1] http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/alt-nvidia-current-smi.1.html

Comment: This only applies to Nvidia drivers....

Comment: @Joren, yes, because the question says "Nvidia GPU"...

Comment: I interpret this answer as "No, unless you switch to the Nvidia drivers"—disappointing, but a valid answer.

Comment: @GerhardBurger the question says "Nvidia GPU" but nouveau is tagged.

Comment: @Blauhirn Yes, nouveau drivers are for Nvidia GPUs.