# Resource monitor for GPU

Tags: graphics, monitoring

I'm looking for a tool similar to [Top](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/top.1.html) but for your graphics card instead of your CPU.

I've got a Nvidia K1000M Quadro graphics card but I would prefer something that would work for all (or most) cards.

Comment: Similar: [Can I view Nvidia GPU usage?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215584/can-i-view-nvidia-gpu-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Radeontop, despite it's name will work for any open source graphics driver.  If you're using proprietary drivers then you'll need to look into nvidia smi (double check, I think that's what it's called).