# Can I view Nvidia GPU usage with nouveau drivers?

Tags: gpu, nouveau

I am using nouveau drivers for my Nvidia GPU. I don't want to change to proprietary drivers. Is there any way I can view my GPU usage similar to `htop`?

There are a couple of old questions [Can I view Nvidia GPU usage?](https://askubuntu.com/q/215584/497359) and [How to measure GPU usage?](https://askubuntu.com/q/387594/497359) . But none of them has a solution which does not use proprietary drivers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems this cannot be done with the open source drivers. To see the GPU usage, you need proprietary drivers.